# Term for a person trying to create unnecessary controversy

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the term for someone who is trying to create controversy out of nothing?

For example, a politician attempting to cause outrage over a very minor thing done by a member of an opposing party.

Comment: Well there's _troublemaker_, of course, and in some contexts, _rabblerouser_. But my personal favorite is _molehillmountainizer_.

Comment: "Stirring the pot" is a common expression for trying to make a bad situation worse.

Comment: And, of course, "witch hunting" almost an exact match for trying to create a controversy out of nothing.

Comment: It's not a single word, but **bomb-thrower** is used in that way, and fairly commonly too when referencing people involved in politics.

Answer (score 3):

As a verb I suggest [to polemicize](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/polemicize)  which is a rather formal term but It may fit in the context you are describing:

> - to practice the art of disputation; engage in polemics or controversy.

- The noun is *polemicist*.

The Free Dictionary

Answer (score 3):

How about **muckraker**?

> **muckrake**
>
> to search for and expose real or alleged corruption, scandal or the like, especially in politics

Answer (score 2):

If you want a colloquial term, such a person is known in Britain as a [*stirrer*.](https://www.google.co.uk/search?site=&source=hp&q=define+stirrer&oq=define+stirrer&gs_l=hp.3..0j0i22i30l2.623.7383.0.8790.19.17.1.0.0.0.376.2388.0j3j5j2.10.0....0...1c.1.64.hp..9.10.2084.0.kEem5CQYTjk)

Someone who stirs trouble, largely for their own amusement.

Answer (score 1):

Well there's **troublemaker**, of course, and in some contexts, **rabblerouser**. But my personal favorite is molehillmountainizer.

– Sven Yargs May 27, 2015

Answer (score 0):

One of these terms may fit:

- propagandist
- narcissistic chaos
- instigator

Comment: I think _instigator_ (along with _fomenter_, perhaps) may be the most accurate one-word match for what the poster is trying to describe. I'm less sold on _propagandist_, and _narcissistic chaos_ seems... odd. But I would happily upvote your answer on the strength of _instigator_ if you gave it more authority by citing (and, if possible, linking to)  a supporting definition from a respectable dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

**mud-slinger** or **mudslinger**

(*noun*) derived from:

**mud-slinging** (*informal noun*): the use of insults and accusations, especially unjust ones, with the aim of damaging the reputation of an opponent.

> Politicians seem to rely on mud-slinging instead of argument.

[*Sources*]  [Wiki](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mudslinging). 
     [Oxford Dict.](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mud-slinging)

Answer (score 0):

> A few noun forms, I proffer-
>
> **bad hat**/troublemaker/mischief-maker.
>
> Someone who deliberately stirs up trouble. ([vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/bad%20hat))

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to name this, and it is very based on how the person does it.

If the politician is arguing about the *person*, not the *argument*, it's an "ad hominem" (literal: about the man).

> Person: "I think the war in Iraq was unjust."
>   Politician: "Well that's obvious coming from a communist hippie."

If the politician is willfully twisting the subject out of scope, it's a "straw man".

> Person: "I think the war in Iraq was unjust."
>   Politician: "China also objected to the war in Iraq. You cannot make our country into a communist society. Communism is clearly inferior."

There are many, many differences.

Although I didn't vet them all, the list on [this webpage](http://www.don-lindsay-archive.org/skeptic/arguments.html) seems to be a good starter resource for differentiating between different types.

Comment: A so want to upvote this. It's not everyday you meet someone familiar with logical fallcy types. But the OP is looking for a term that describes the person, not the process. You might have been misled by the title, which I have edited.

Comment: @TusharRaj Its my honest opinion the world would be a better place if these things were taught to everyone. You see so many problems arise from people using these devices (sometimes unintentionally). Anyway, I did misinterpret it from the title. Will think on a general word for the person, although I think "politician" is already aptly put :)